# Multiple versions of gcc / g++ affects

Tags: 12.04, compiling, gcc, c++

I have a fairly simple question, and yet couldn't find an answer anywhere I looked.

In my workplace there is a CI server with ubuntu 12.04 installed, that server uses the default c/c++ binaries ( 4.6.3 ) versions of the compilers. There is now a project which requires new versions of the compilers ( ones that include c++11 ).

**3 Questions:**

1. Will installing gcc-4.8 & g++4.8 break / change stuff which is used by the existing 4.6.3 versions ? ( maybe there are shared libs dependencies which can get overridden ? )
2. Is it safe to assume gcc-4.8 & gcc-4.8 are not going to cause
   a situation where a build ( which relies on 4.6.3 ) passes, but in reality the build code behaviour changes ? ( maybe due to being optimized differently ? )
3. Most importantly, Can several versions of the compilers be installed on a system without breaking previous versions of them ?

Please bear with me as c/c++ are not programming languages I ever got to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Will installing gcc-4.8 & g++4.8 break / change stuff which is used by the existing 4.6.3 versions ?

No.

> 2. Is it safe to assume gcc-4.8 & gcc-4.8 are not going to cause a situation where a build ( which relies on 4.6.3 ) passes, but in
>      reality the build code behaviour changes ? ( maybe due to being
>      optimized differently ? )

Depends on how they rely on 4.6.3. Does your build process invoke `gcc` or `gcc-4.6`? If the latter, there shouldn't be any changes. If the former, you should use the alternatives system to configure `gcc` to use `gcc-4.6`, or change your processes to use `gcc-4.6`/`g++-4.6`. (Lookup `update-alternatives`.)

> 3. Most importantly, Can several versions of the compilers be installed on a system without breaking previous versions of them ?

Yes, if you're installing using reasonably built debian packages. It's not unusual to have multiple versions of GCC installed.

Comment: Regarding your answer on #2 - AFAIK installation of g++ 4.8 sets up a bin called /usr/bin/g++-4.8; thus, it shouldn't affect anything, this in turn means I can reference the versioned binary during the new project build process, Correct?

Comment: Yes - the versioned binaries should remain unaffected.